RASM-86 versions 1.1 and 1.2 for DOS
Have versions 1.1 and 1.2 of RASM-86 (the 8086 assembler by Digital Research) ever been released for DOS? A download link would be the best (Google doesn't give anything useful), but I'd appreciate any info about these versions.
I was able to find versions 1.0 (as part of DRI Programmer's Utilities 1.0 for PC-DOS), 1.3 and 1.4a online. Version 1.4a was used (as well as MASM) to compile the kernel (ibmbio.com and ibmdos.com) of DR DOS 7.

In the SvarDOS repo and lDOS repo of Enhanced DR-DOS we ported all the ".a86" files that were assembled, as you mentioned, using RASM-86 1.4a to build with JWasm instead (eg). The lDOS repo subsequently ported all uses of JWasm for the kernel to NASM. We did this because RASM-86 shipped without sources and JWasm is based on OpenWatcom and thus not entirely FLOSS.

Is the a project page for IDOS, where I can read some intro text? Google gives me unrelated projects when I search for IDOS.

Not really. There's the web page with some pointers and the related repos lDOS boot, lDOS MBR, lClock, lDebug, lmacros, and one that's called just lDOS. This last one actually slots into the latest revision of RxDOS 7.2x (which I no longer work on) but I'll probably re-use parts of it for MS-DOS later.
